# Issue with Wordpress category search

Tags: categories, query, search

I made multiple custom search on my wordpress site to find post with category search. Like this:

```
    <select id="category-select" name="category-select">
       <option value="6">Todo</option>
       <option value="7">Spain</option>
       <option value="8">Europe</option>
       <option value="30">Rest of the World</option>
      </select>
<input type="text" id="autoc-input" name="autoc-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="">
```

My form sends correctly all the parameters, for example if i search Barcelona for the category Spain i got this url:

> ?s=Barcelona&cat=7

I can't get any result from this query, but if i search just for my input or category. With this i got all the post from the category on the search page:

> ?s=cat=7

And with this all the post that contains Barcelona.

> ?s=Barcelona

I can't find the issue to get the results with more than one parameter. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress search is very incomplete to do good post search. I find an answer editing search.php on the top of my template file.

```
$s = $_GET['s'];
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$custom_query_args = array(
                        's' => $s,
                        'cat' => $cat,
                        'posts_per_page'   => 11,
                        'order'            => 'DESC',
                        'post_type'        => 'post',
                        'post_status'      => 'publish'
                    );

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;
```

Like this i got all the results of the selected category.

Answer (score 0):

You can search post by modify the query using `pre_get_post` filter. add this code inside your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'search_by_category');
function search_by_category($wp_query)
{
    if (isset($_GET['cat']) && !is_admin()) {
        $wp_query->set('category__in', array($_GET['cat']));
    }
}
```

Before using any query variable you must have to register/add using add_query_var.

```
function add_category_query_string() {

    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('cat');

}

add_filter('init', 'add_category_query_string');
```

let me know if it works for you .

Comment: I still have the same issue. Wordpress already search by category but when i add two parameters i dont get any result. I made my custom search template (outside from wordpress search) and everything works fine but that dont fix wordpress search page

Comment: I have edited my code please check and try @MidouCloud

Comment: That didnt work but i find a solution editing the query in the template file search.php

Comment: Great ! @MidouCloud